# Python libmysqlclient segfault (MySQLdb)

Tags: python, mysql-python, libmysql, python-db-api

I am writing an SQL wrapper over MySQLdb.

Sometime during execution I am getting the following error in DMSG and the process crushes:

```
python[xxx]: segfault at c8 ip 00007fa1add6b882 sp 00007fa1abb77c60 error 4 in 
libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0[7fa1adcd7000+1d0000]
```

How can i debug this fault? 
Did someone encounter this kind of error before ? The bug is obviously not in the script, but I assume I am doing some bad calls that trigger that bug in the client.

Any suggestions on how to solve it ?

Python 2.6.6 with libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 running on Debian 6.0

Thank You

Comment: Long time...but did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue then calling `MySQLdb.connect` from Python 3

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here to solve your problem. However, if you are using threads, give each thread it's own connection object; don't try to share them between threads. That is the most likely cause of a segfault in this case.